# Generating and saving graph objects iteratively in R

Tags: r, igraph

I am using the `igraph` package in R to work with networks. I run MonteCarlo simulations, and would like to store the graph generated in each run in a file, that I could retrieve later.

Here is a sample code of what I am trying to do

```
for (i in 1:5){
  g<- erdos.renyi.game(1000, 1/1000)
  save(g,file='foo.Rdata')
}
```

How do I append the newer graph objects to the same file. Currently, save, just replaces the existing file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `save` function saves data in a binary format that does not allow appending. It would be better to generate the list of graphs all at once and then save the collection to a file at the end

```
graphs <- replicate(5, erdos.renyi.game(1000, 1/1000))
save(graphs, file='foo.Rdata')
```

In a list, you can get to each of the individual graphs using `[[]]`. For example

```
graphs[[1]]
graphs[[2]]
...etc
```